# Mapping properties with custom attributes

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to map two entities with different property name in each entity. I'm mapping ViewModel Entity to Entity framework entity. Is there any out of box feature to add some custom attributes to my viewmodel entity proerties, instead of doing one to one mapping for properties with different property names?. Please find the sample below...

```cs
public class FooModel
{
    [customAttribute("FooId")]
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    [customAttribute("FooName")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int FooId{ get; set; }
    public string FooName{ get; set; }
}
```

i want to map customattribute names with actual property name on the Foo class. I don't want to map explicitly since i have numerous classes in my application.

I am using the folowing extension method, but I don't know how to map destination property dynamically in `MapFrom`

```cs
public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> CustomMapper<TSource, TDestination>
    (this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDestination> expression)
{
    var flags = BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
    var sourceType = typeof(TSource);
    var destinationProperties = typeof(TDestination).GetProperties(flags);

    foreach (var property in destinationProperties)
    {
        var props = sourceType.GetProperties();
       // props.Select(s=>s.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PropertyMapper)).Single(m=>m.)
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var attributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(prop);
            if (attributes.Count() == 1 && ((PropertyMapper)attributes[0]).Name == property.Name)
            {
         //  expression.ForMember(property.Name,s=>s.MapFrom<TDestination>(t=>t.));
            }

        }

        if (sourceType.GetProperty(property.Name, flags) == null)
        {

            expression.ForMember(property.Name, opt => opt.Ignore());
        }
    }
    return expression;
}
```

Comment: It's not a bad idea, but I'm afraid you have to write it yourself. On the other hand, writing the attributes is almost the same as writing explicit mappings. Also, with these string literals you no longer have the compile-time checks you'd have with AutoMapper mappings.

Answer (score 0):

using attributes in view model could be make your view error prone while model binding, as you want to handle this issue by creating a generic attribute what do you want to do when you want have to cast your mode to view model? do you want to use the same attribute in your model?? try to make your domain model POCO.
if you notice, in this case you are making your code a little bit complex by using attribute both in model and view model, hum?? it's better to have a gateway to handle this issue and the best place to do that is an extension method to mappers, for example I have this model and viewmodel:

```
  public class Blog
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }


    public class BlogViewModel
    {

        public Guid PostId { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

  public static class BlogMapper
    {
   public static IEnumerable<BlogViewModel> ConvertToPostListViewModel(this IEnumerable<Blog> posts)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Blog, BlogViewModel>()
                .ForMember(blo => blo.PostId, bl => bl.MapFrom(b => b.Id));
            return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Blog>, IEnumerable<BlogViewModel>>(posts);
        }
    }
```

by the way, in some cases mapping and object to another is not simple in this example and I don't think that it would be possible to handle them via an attribute, and making several per case attribute class could make the code dirty and hard to read. Model and ViewModel should know nothing about each others members and also do a task about mapping members.(SOLID principle)

Comment: Thanks Ehsan, its not  new application, we are going to implement it on a existing application. So its hard to change the properties and if we are going to do one to one mapping using "Mapfrom" then automapper is the not the rite tool.

Comment: but you have talked about Automapper in the title of your question!

Comment: I don't understand why the ViewModel can't know about the Entity/Model? It's always a 1:1 mapping anyway and they're strongly coupled; you'll never use another Entity/Model with a given View. The view is essentially a "converted" version of the Entity (or some other non-entity data). SOLID principle is valid when it's useful.